# Prove that two vectors are perpendicular without having coordinates of vectors

Tags: vectors

Homework: Two vectors that are $\neq\vec{0}$ have a dot product equal to 0. Prove that they are perpendicular.

Comment: What is your definition of 'perpendicular'?

Comment: Did you know that a dot product is the length of one vector times the length of the other vector times the cosine of the angle between them? In formula: $\vec a \cdot \vec b = a b \cos \theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Since the two vectors aren't null vectors, we have: $$\vec v\bullet\vec u=\|\vec v\|\|\vec u\|\cos\theta=0\iff \cos\theta=0$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.

Comment: and $\cos\theta=0$ means $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ so they are perpendicular??

Comment: @user147572 Exactly! Keep up the great work! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Comment: oh thanks, this really helps

Comment: @user147572 You're welcome!